# Is there a way to make gridlines in the scene view more visible?

Tags: unity-game-engine

The gridlines in the scene view are quite faint in general. Can the brightness be adjusted or could they be made more visible in anyway? If yes, how can this be done?

Comment: Its interesting how this has been marked as a duplicate. I actually saw "Change the default scene grid color" title and didn't bother to even check the question because I thought the grid lines were faded out or something, which is the effect of using a grayish color for the lines. I didn't see my problem as a color problem per say. This question is being marked as duplicate on the basis of the solution not the question. Changing the scene color might not necessarily imply making the gridlines more visible for someone looking for a solution for either.

Comment: The problem is that the background color(Skybox) and the grid color are very close. I do think that this is a duplicate since changing the grid color is probably the only fix. The title should have been *"How to change grid color to be more visible"*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `Edit` > `Preferences` > `Colors`

And change the color of the `Grid`

[image]